# Find named elements in WinRT XAML page

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime

I'm trying to add notes represented by icons into a RichTextBlock and then add Tapped event handlers to all of them. I found out that I can't add handlers into XAML before I insert it programmatically into the page, so I need to find each element with a certain naming pattern and add a handler to each one.

Here's my code:

```
private void assignNoteHandlers()
    {
        //For each note expected on screen
        for ( int i = 0; i < currentTextFile.noteCount; i++ ){
            try
            {
                string noteName = String.Format("note{0}", i);
                Image noteIcon = (Image)pageRoot.FindName(noteName);
                noteIcon.Tapped += noteIcon_Tapped;
            }
            catch
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("The Image note{0} was not found", i);
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
```

When I look at the screen, I can see the note icon inserted into the text as it should be.

The text on screen comes from an HTML file, into which I programmatically insert this string for each note:

```
string noteXML = string.Format("<note name=\"note{0}\" src=\"Assets/TEMPNoteIcon.png\" />", i);
```

That psuedo-HTML gets converted into XAML with this xslt template:

```
<xsl:template match="NOTE | note">
<Span>
  <InlineUIContainer>
    <Image Stretch="None" >
      <xsl:attribute name="x:Name">
        <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <!-- DISABLED
      <xsl:attribute name="Name">
        <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      -->
      <xsl:attribute name="Source">
        <xsl:value-of select="@src"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </Image>
  </InlineUIContainer>
</Span>
</xsl:template>
```

I have tried using both "Name" and "x:Name" above (but I can't do both at once).

So, my problem is that in the first block of code (which runs last), Image noteIcon is always null.

I know this is a very complicated question, but can anyone help me figure this out?

EDIT: Here's the code that fills the RichTextBlock (I downloaded it from the web),

```
private static async void HtmlChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Get the target RichTextBlock
        RichTextBlock richText = d as RichTextBlock;
        if (richText == null) return;

        // Wrap the value of the Html property in a div and convert it to a new RichTextBlock
        string xhtml = string.Format("<div>{0}</div>", e.NewValue as string);
        RichTextBlock newRichText = null;
        if (Windows.ApplicationModel.DesignMode.DesignModeEnabled)
        {
            // In design mode we swallow all exceptions to make editing more friendly
            string xaml = "";
            try {
                xaml = await ConvertHtmlToXamlRichTextBlock(xhtml);
                newRichText = (RichTextBlock)XamlReader.Load(xaml);
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                string errorxaml = string.Format(@"
                    <RichTextBlock 
                     xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'
                     xmlns:x='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml'
                    >
                        <Paragraph>An exception occurred while converting HTML to XAML: {0}</Paragraph>
                        <Paragraph />
                        <Paragraph>HTML:</Paragraph>
                        <Paragraph>{1}</Paragraph>
                        <Paragraph />
                        <Paragraph>XAML:</Paragraph>
                        <Paragraph>{2}</Paragraph>
                    </RichTextBlock>",
                    ex.Message,
                    EncodeXml(xhtml),
                    EncodeXml(xaml)
                );
                newRichText = (RichTextBlock)XamlReader.Load(errorxaml);
            } // Display a friendly error in design mode.
        }
        else
        {
            // When not in design mode, we let the application handle any exceptions
            string xaml = await ConvertHtmlToXamlRichTextBlock(xhtml);
            newRichText = (RichTextBlock)XamlReader.Load(xaml);
        }

        // Move the blocks in the new RichTextBlock to the target RichTextBlock
        richText.Blocks.Clear();
        if (newRichText != null)
        {
            for (int i = newRichText.Blocks.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                Block b = newRichText.Blocks[i];
                newRichText.Blocks.RemoveAt(i);
                richText.Blocks.Insert(0, b);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you are adding these images to the rich text box yourself - why do you need to find them again? Just store references to these when you add them there.

Comment: @FilipSkakun The images are added in the XSLT conversion, which means I never have a reference to them in the C# code. I added them that way because I didn't know how to add content to a RichTextBlock otherwise. If you know how, I'd appreciate if you could tell me so I can skip all this complicated nonsense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out my code wasn't waiting for the RichTextBlock to be filled before trying to attach the note handlers to the images. Odd, but simple.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create your RichTextBlock through XAML. You can do it like this:

```
var rtb = new RichTextBlock();
var paragraph = new Paragraph();
paragraph.Inlines.Add(new Run { Text = "Hello" });
paragraph.Inlines.Add(new InlineUIContainer { Child = new Button { Content = "World" } });
rtb.Blocks.Add(paragraph);
((Grid)this.Content).Children.Add(rtb);
```

Comment: The trouble is, the images have to be able to go anywhere, not just in between blocks. My current method lets them go inline with the text.

Comment: This is not in between blocks. This is inside of a paragraph. You can add another text Run after the inline ui container to mix it up more. There's only a single paragraph in my example.

Comment: Okay, the next problem is doing that inside of the [HTML2XAML code](http://html2xaml.codeplex.com/). Yikes.

Comment: That sounds like a different problem. Have I answered your question sufficiently?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I still never make the blocks in C# - the code I got (actually different from the one I linked but similar idea) puts the XAML into blocks and never gives me access to the contents of the blocks.

Comment: OK, can you share a code sample for how you are processing the XSLT and loading the XAML? I've checked and FindName seems to work fine, so the problem you are experiencing seems to be in the code that you haven't posted.

Comment: Added two new snippets to my question, above. Thanks for helping me with this!

Comment: That's still not a good repro sample since I can't see clearly what the string is you are trying to load with `XamlReader.Load()` and where the elements are inside of it. A good repro sample would have just the specific XAML string being loaded with `XamlReader.Load()` and then the code that tries to find the element by name. One thing I noticed now though is that you are calling pageRoot.FindName(). Your page root might use a different [`namescope`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh758291.aspx) than the RichTextBlock. You could try calling FindName on the rtb instead.

Comment: Also - if your names are not unique within the rtb - finding elements by name might not work. In such case I would try using something like the Tag property to identify elements matching your search and simply scan through all blocks of the rtb, all inlines of the paragraphs and find all `InlineUIContainer`s then all the elements inside of them. Otherwise - check the XAML namescopes article I mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: Ah! Found the problem! The assignNoteHandlers() function runs before the XAML is put into the rich text block. Wacky. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: One last question, now: how do I make code (specifically, the assignNoteHandlers() function) run after the contents of the RichTextBlock have been updated?

Comment: Make the call to `assignNoteHandlers()` after you updated the `RichTextBlock`. Not sure what your specific flow is. You could use `SemaphoreSlim` or `TaskCompletionSource` and await these in `assignNoteHandlers` before you run the rest of its code.